# Show tag previously hidden with if case in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have the following xml:

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <SubChild th:if="${subChild.exist}" name="Nikola" surname="Tesla">
        <Birtday>01.01.1990</Birtday>
        <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
            <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
        </Parent>
    </SubChild>
</Child>
```

I am populating this tag with data from java and in some cases I don't have this SubChild for which I have that if case, but I always have the parent which I need to show it.

What I want to achieve is even in a case where this SubChild doesn't exist and it's hidden with the if case, to show the Parent tag since he will always be there. To make this tag Parent mandatory I would say.

I have one solution which is:

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <SubChild th:if="${subChild.exist}" name="Nikola" surname="Tesla">
        <Birtday>01.01.1990</Birtday>
        <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
            <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
        </Parent>
    </SubChild>
    <Parent th:if="${!subChild.exist}" name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
        <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
    </Parent>
</Child>
```

But in this solution is repetition of the Parent tag twice. And in my real scenario it is a huge tag which I want to avoid repeating it. 
My question is: is it possible to display this tag even if the previously mentioned if case is false, without repeating the same code for the Parent.

In the end my result should be:

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
        <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
    </Parent>
</Child>
```

Comment: _a huge tag which I want to avoid repeating_ - Have you considered creating a [Thymeleaf fragment](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#fragments) containing the `<Parent>...</Parent>` tag? You can insert a fragment wherever you need it, using `th:insert` Your solution (with 2 `if` statements) would be less cluttered, using this approach. Fragments can be parameterized - for example, if each of the 2 occurrences need to display different sets of values.

Comment: I haven't used that fragment until now. I will be able to put the parent tag when I want? @andrewjames

Comment: Yes - but first, I want to check: At the end of your question, you show an example "my result should be...". In that example, there are three `<Birthday>` tags. Should there only be two? Should this tag be removed from the example: `<Birtday>01.01.1990</Birtday>`?

Comment: Actually that was a mistake, removed that additional <Birthday> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using fragments, you can do the following:

Create a fragment for the "parent" section of your XML. In my example this is in a file called "parent.xml?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<th:block th:fragment="parent_fragment">
    <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
        <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
    </Parent>
</th:block>
```

Then use the fragment in your main XML as follows:

(just to note, for my own testing, I changed your `if` condition - you can change it back to your version)

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <th:block th:if="${subChild} != null">
    <SubChild name="Nikola" surname="Tesla">
        <Birtday>01.01.1990</Birtday>
        <th:block th:replace = "parent.xml :: parent_fragment"></th:block>
    </SubChild>        
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:if="${subChild} == null">
        <th:block th:replace = "parent.xml :: parent_fragment"></th:block>
    </th:block>
</Child>
```

This generates two XML outputs as follows:

When subchild does not exist (or, in my case, when it is null):

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
        <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
    </Parent>
</Child>
```

When subchild exists (not null):

```
<Child name="Filip" surname="Trajkovski">
    <Birtday>01.01.1999</Birtday>
    <SubChild name="Nikola" surname="Tesla">
        <Birtday>01.01.1990</Birtday>
        <Parent name="Unknown" surname="Uknown">
            <Birthday>01.01.1990</Birthday>
        </Parent>
    </SubChild>        
</Child>
```

Now, you only have to define the (potentially very large) `<parent>...</parent>` section in one place.